# MVC 3: Communicating between partial view and view via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I have a page that lists users (List.vbhtml), and each user has an 'Edit' link. The edit link makes an Ajax request:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Player", New With {.id = currentItem.PlayerId}, New AjaxOptions() with { .UpdateTargetId="edit"})
```

The Edit method in my controller returns a partial view (_Edit) which contains a form. After the form has been submitted, I want to hide the edit form (not a problem), and then reload the list of users. *This is what I am struggling with.*

How do I let the parent view (List.vbhtml) know I should reload the list (which would be done using a Ajax Get request)?

I can't do this from the Edit partial view, because the Edit partial view shouldn't know about the List view, only the other way around (List view knows about the partial view).

My current solution is to raise a custom event when the edit is complete in _Edit.vbhtml, and capture it in List.vbhtml:

**_Edit.vbhtml:**

```
//let anyone listening know the edit is complete
$(document).trigger('PersonEditComplete');
```

**List.vbhtml**

```
//when player edit is complete, reload the player list
$(document).bind('PersonEditComplete', function () {
    Player.List.Reload();
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just invoke a jQuery event such as .remove() once your form is submitted? The .remove() method removes the element from the DOM tree.

Comment: That would achieve hiding the edit form, which isn't the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery .[ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) event handler. You have to check if the XHR method is GET or POST. Get will be after loading user edit form, POST would be after subbmiting it.

So if ajaxComplete fires after POST call then you should refresh users list via Ajax.

Comment: Not a bad idea, however I've updated my original question with what I do now. I used the jQuery bind/trigger methods to raise a catch an event.